# Having multiple keywords separated by comma in the title of the page?

Tags: seo, html, meta-tags, title, meta-description

I want to target multiple keywords with same piece of content (*I am thinking to add multiple keywords separated by commas in title and description of the page*). So, is it the right approach or I am making any mistake?

Comment: Is your only purpose in doing this to rank better for the comma-separated keywords?

Comment: Yes. I want to rank easily for long trailing (multiple [related to each other]) keywords with the same page. What I am thinking wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using multiple related keywords in the title and description separated by commas, you'll actually be creating a bad overall user experience for your readers and users.

I'd suggest not using multiple keywords (even if they are related) in your title and meta description. Instead, only focus on using your main target keyword once or twice.

Comment: Thanks @Ruben I would love to ask for an example.

Comment: @ManishShahi well if you could share the target keyword for your page I can give you my input?

Comment: NFT Calendar, Upcoming NFT and NFT Drop

Comment: Seeing as these keywords are closely related I don't think you'll be making a mistake by using all of them on the same page. Here are my suggestions:

Title: Upcoming NFT and NFT Drops - Check out our NFT calendar
Description: Stay updated on the latest NFT drops and upcoming non-fungible tokens by using our NFT calendar.

Comment: That's clean. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used a pipe character (|) to separate my keyword strings, but Google also recognizes commas. I use a similar approach to my SEO; I include keyword phrases that are supported by the content and try to limit it to no more than 3 very closely related terms. Example here: https://driltech.net/mud-motor-drilling.php

If I have trouble narrowing it down I look at the possibility I need to refine my keywords or I need to move some of the content to a page of its own. Each page is your elevator pitch, it should be focused and precise(ish). This is always an issue when I am trying to optimize overview-type pages because it covers a broad swath of content and you know you can't win on every term.

I found this [article about writing title tags and meta descriptions](https://growdnd.com/blog/title-tags-and-meta-descriptions/), it is from 2015 but everything pretty much still rings true.

Comment: Thanks @TexasB. I have a quick question from the link that you referred in the last paragraph. I want to ask as per article title and H1 tag shouldn't be same .i.e, repeating. Can you explain why? And what should we do to make H1 tag differentiate than the TITLE tag of the page?

Comment: @ManishShahi I don't stress about them being the same as long as the H1 is the "most right" choice for the page and the user experience. Example 1. https://www.mavtechglobal.com/solutions/dcsnext/ Example 2. https://www.mavtechglobal.com/enterprise-integration/  Screaming Frog is brilliant for helping you track your titles, H1s, and tons more, even the free version.  Maybe think of title tags as description(s), and the H1 as the introduction.